# Import Gmail Contact Brithday and Pic in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail

I want to import the contact of gmail. I have successfully import the Name,phone and email address of the friends but I want to import the pic and DOB of friend too.

I have done lot of R&D but not found and solution. Please help …….

Answer (score 0):

Check **Google Contacts API**

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_contacts_photo

> To retrieve a contact's photo, send an authorized GET request to the
>   contact's photo link URL.
>
> The URL is of the form:
>
> https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/{userEmail}/{contactId}
>
> With the appropriate values in place of userEmail and contactID.

```
public static void DownloadPhoto(ContactsRequest cr, Uri contactURL)
{
  Contact contact = cr.Retrieve<Contact>(contactURL);

  Stream photoStream = cr.GetPhoto(contact);
  FileStream outStream = File.OpenWrite("test.jpg");
  byte[] buffer = new byte[photoStream.length];

  photoStream.Read(buffer, 0, photoStream.length);
  outStream.Write(buffer, 0, photoStream.length);
  photoStream.Close();
  outStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply ..
But can we get the birthday of friend. Please let me know.

Comment: It will probably be en *extendedProperty*. Check the documentation I linked to.

Comment: What is Uri contactURL in DownloadPhoto method